# How does PHP's foreach handle references?

Tags: php, foreach, reference, xdebug

While playing with xdebug's reference counting feature, i came across this strange behaviour:

```
$a = array('foo', 'bar');
xdebug_debug_zval('a');

foreach ($a as $key => $s) {
    xdebug_debug_zval('a');
    echo "$s\n";
    unset($a[$key]);
    xdebug_debug_zval('a');
}
```

The output is:

```
a: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)=array (0 => (refcount=1, is_ref=0)='foo', 1 => (refcount=1, is_ref=0)='bar')
a: (refcount=3, is_ref=0)=array (0 => (refcount=2, is_ref=0)='foo', 1 => (refcount=1, is_ref=0)='bar')
foo
a: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)=array (1 => (refcount=2, is_ref=0)='bar')
a: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)=array (1 => (refcount=3, is_ref=0)='bar')
bar
a: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)=array ()
```

Why does `refcount` of `a` jumps up to three? Maybe because each local `$s` keeps a reference to it? If this is the case where is it saved? Then i see that `refcount` is increased by one for either the first or the second item of the array, depending on the cycle being executed. But why `refcount` of the second item is increased by one after i unset the first one?

Clearly, what i wanted to achieve is this:

```
$a = array('foo', 'bar');
xdebug_debug_zval('a');

$tot = count($a);
for ($i = 0; $i < $tot; $i++) {
    xdebug_debug_zval('a');
    echo $a[$i]."\n";
    unset($a[$i]);
    xdebug_debug_zval('a');
}
```

which has this output:

```
a: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)=array (0 => (refcount=1, is_ref=0)='foo', 1 => (refcount=1, is_ref=0)='bar')
a: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)=array (0 => (refcount=1, is_ref=0)='foo', 1 => (refcount=1, is_ref=0)='bar')
foo
a: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)=array (1 => (refcount=1, is_ref=0)='bar')
a: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)=array (1 => (refcount=1, is_ref=0)='bar')
bar
a: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)=array ()
```

Is it possible to achieve this result using `foreach`?

Comment: This article doesn't mention 'foreach' but explains PHP references in detail. rather more detail than most of us need but seems fairly complete ;-/ [PHP references explained](http://derickrethans.nl/talks/phparch-php-variables-article.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to get a handle on what is going in the background:

```
print_r(array_keys(get_defined_vars()));
print_r(array_values(get_defined_vars()));
```

It will output all assigned variables at any given point in a script. Try moving it to different points in your file. See the changes and make adjustments accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Besides if you want to work with only references then you can simply add the "&"(Ampersand) sign before the handling variable.strong text